# Using recursive file search and exclude startswith() with pathlib

Tags: python, for-loop, operating-system, pathlib

I want to search recursive for all files in all folders with pathlib, but I want to exclude hidden system files that start with '.' (like '.DS_Store')
But I can't find a function like startswith in pathlib. How can I achieve startswith in pathlib?
I know how to do it with os.

```
def recursive_file_count(scan_path):
    root_directory = Path(scan_path)
    fcount = len([f for f in root_directory.glob('**/*') if f.startswith(".")])
    print(fcount)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**startswith()** is a Python string method, see https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/startswith.html

Since your f is a Path object, you have to convert it into a string first via `str(f)`

```
def recursive_file_count(scan_path):
    root_directory = Path(scan_path)
    fcount = len([f for f in root_directory.glob('**/*') if str(f).startswith(".")])
    print(fcount)
```

Answer (score 4):

there is a kind of `startswith` - You can use `pathlib.Path.is_relative_to()` :

`pathlib.Path.is_relative_to()` was added in Python 3.9, if You want to use it on earlier versions (3.6 upwards), You need to use the backport pathlib3x:

```
$> python -m pip install pathlib3x
$> python
>>> p = Path('/etc/passwd')
>>> p.is_relative_to('/etc')
True
>>> p.is_relative_to('/usr')
False
```

you can find pathlib3x on [github](https://github.com/bitranox/pathlib3x) or [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib3x)

But this still will not help for Your example, because You want to skip FILES that start with '.' - so Your solution is correct - but not very efficient:

```
def recursive_file_count(scan_path):
    root_directory = Path(scan_path)
    fcount = len([f for f in root_directory.glob('**/*') if not str(f.name).startswith(".")])
    print(fcount)
```

Imagine You have 2 million files in the *scan_path*, this would create a list with 2 million pathlib.Path objects. Whow, that will take some time and memory ...

It would be better to have a kind of filter like fnmatch or something for the glob function - I am considering it for pathlib3x.

The Path.glob() returns a [generator iterator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) which needs much less memory.

so in order to save memory, the solution can be :

```
def recursive_file_count(scan_path):
    root_directory = Path(scan_path)
    fcount = 0
    # we only have one instance of f at the time
    for f in root_directory.glob('**/*'):
        if not str(f.name).startswith(".")]):
            fcount = fcount + 1
    print(count)
```

---

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm the author of the pathlib3x library.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**My solution:**

```
def recursive_file_count(scan_path):
    root_directory = Path(scan_path)
    fcount = len([f for f in root_directory.glob('**/*') if not str(f.name).startswith(".")])
    print(fcount)
```